# How to test several modulo values in one line with Python?

Tags: python, modulo

Suppose I have a value that could be in the range of [28,32] or a multiple of a number in that range.

Is there a way that I can test this in one line using the modulo operator?

Tried:

```
if value % (28 or 29 or 30 or 31 or 32) == 0:
    # do stuff
```

And some similar variations. I tried to search, as I'm sure this is a common operation, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` to check the truthiness of multiple similar expressions:

```
if any(value % n == 0 for n in (28, 29, 30, 31, 32)):
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a job for `any`

```
   if any( value % m == 0 for m in range(28,33) ):
       #do stuff
```